# Al hacer click en la pantalla crear un div

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Necesito que a hacer clic en cualquier lado de la pantalla se cree un *div*; mi código no funciona y no entiendo como arreglarlo, además, no parece muy eficiente; agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Tengo esto:

```
let body = document.querySelector("body");

body.addEventListener("click", crearDiv);

function crearDiv (event) {
    let x = event.clientX;
    let y = event.clientY;
   
    let div = document.createElement("div");
  
    div.style.left = x + "px";
    div.style.top = y + "px";
    div.addEventListener("click", existeDiv);
  
    if (event.target.nodeName != "DIV"){
        body.appendChild(div);
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Al poner posicionamiento x,y debes poner en estilo: `position:absolute` o relativo. Además si no tiene texto o contenido no te vas a percatar de que ha puesto el elemento amenos que veas en el inspector.

```js
itemA.addEventListener("click", crearDiv);

function crearDiv (event) {
    let x = event.clientX;
    let y = event.clientY;
   
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML="x";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.left = x + "px";
    div.style.top = y + "px";
    itemA.append(div);

}
```

```html
<div id="itemA" style="width:1000px;height:1000px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No pusiste tu código CSS en la pregunta, pero las posibles causas de que no funcione como esperas:

1. El cuerpo de la página no ocupa toda la pantalla
2. No estás asignando posición absoluta (o relativa) a los elementos creados
3. No se ven los elementos porque no tienen contenido ni medidas específicas o alguna otra propiedad como color de fondo, borde, sombra, etc.

No parece óptimo porque primero creas el elemento y hasta el final compruebas dónde se hizo el clic; esa validación se debe hacer antes.

```js
let body = document.body;

body.addEventListener("click", crearDiv);

function crearDiv (event) {
    // Solo cuando se haga clic en el cuerpo, no en otros divs
    // Compara directamente elementos
    if(event.target != body) {
        return;
    }
    let x = event.clientX;
    let y = event.clientY;
   
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    // Asignar clase para posicionar y poner medidas
    div.classList.add('div-abs');
  
    div.style.left = x + "px";
    div.style.top = y + "px";
    div.addEventListener("click", existeDiv);
    // Agregar
    body.appendChild(div);
}

function existeDiv(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

```css
body {
    /* El cuerpo debe ocupar toda la pantalla */
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.div-abs {
    /* Posición absoluta para colocar donde se haga clic */
    position: absolute;
    /* Esto es solo para hacerlo visible */
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```